# Htaccess redirect 301 not working, everything seems fine

Tags: apache, redirect

I am trying to redirect valleyrain.net/projects/desert-trails-bike-park/ to https://valleyrain.com/project/desert-trails-bmx-park/ but for some reason it's not working. Can someone suggest why?

.htaccess file is working, so should not be the reason

```
RewriteEngine On
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.valleyrain\.net$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^valleyrain\.net$
RewriteRule ^projects\/desert-trails-bike-park/?$ "https\:\/\/valleyrain\.com\/project\/desert-trails-bmx-park\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: remove the `^` from
`RewriteRule projects\/desert-trails-bike-park/?$ "https\:\/\/valleyrain\.com\/project\/desert-trails-bmx-park\/" [R=301,L]`